# Pandas groupby with mode function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve a particular problem, and I got stuck in this case.

```
data.groupby(["department","region", "gender"])["age"].transform(lambda x: x.mode())
```

Why all values are changed to nan?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MHgpq1UejZoAZ2StwBaXS5u2bvzxMOH8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to fill "education" column missing values using groupby and mode.

Answer (score 2):

`mode` returns a Series containing the mode (mode**s** if there are two), not actually a scalar value (e.g. an int). So get the first value using `.iloc[0]`:

```
data.groupby(["department","region", "gender"])["age"].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
```